# Deploying war file in google app engine by creating a java class using the jar specific to deploy it

Tags: java, google-app-engine, executable-jar

i have searched for various solutions in need of creating a simple java class with a deploy method. This deploy method should get the path of the war file and deploy it in app engine google account. i tried to get the jars of it and use these methods.. but i didnt had any details for help even after searching. so any good suggestions? on how to deploy it directly in google app engine

Comment: A bit confusing question, Either you are asking if some API is like this is available or not. OR you know about the API, and asking details of the same. Share your findings first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean programmatically deploy to GAE?

Sure, it's possible. Take a look at [AppCfg source](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/java/src/main/com/google/appengine/tools/admin/AppCfg.java?r=182) and extract classes relevant to deploy.

Comment: yes i needed to know the deploying done programatically.thanks for the help i will check on it.